# How to correctly pass initial value of transition_params in tensorflow linear chain CRF

Tags: tensorflow, crf

I'm trying to use the linear chain CRF in my work. I took the help of the example usage code provided in -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.0/tensorflow/contrib/crf

My question is how to supply some initial value of "transition_params" in "crf_log_likelihood()". For concreteness of the example, say, I want to initialize it with standard random normal distribution. In the [api doc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.0/tensorflow/contrib/crf/python/ops/crf.py#L128), I saw that "transition_params" can, in fact, be passed as an input argument. Inside the method I see that if no "transition_params" is passed, it is obtained by doing a "vs.get_variable()" with name = "transitions".

So should I do something similar to this, before creating the 'crf_log_likelihood' op? Something like -- transition_params = vs.get_variable("transitions", [num_tags, num_tags], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer()) -- and then change the call of "crf_log_likelihood()" to "log_likelihood, transition_params = tf.contrib.crf.crf_log_likelihood(unary_scores, y_t, sequence_lengths_t, transition_params)"?

Answer (score 1):

The `get_variable()` inside the definition of `crf_log_likelihood()` will create a fresh, randomly-initialized variable to represent the transition parameters, if you don't provide one yourself. You only need to provide an explicit `transition_params` if you don't want the default behavior.

To understand the behavior of `get_variable()`, see here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/sharing_variables#get_variable

Hope that helps!